# Java ERROR: package X is declared in the unnamed module, but module Y does not read it

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, module-info

I am trying to make my javafx project to create an Excel file. One of the first steps for it would be `XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();` for which to work I need `import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;`  to work. But when I try to run the program I get an error:

```
  (package org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel is declared in module org.apache.poi.ooxml, but module group.proga does not read it)
```

I use IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1 (Community Edition). I downloaded **Apache POI 5.2.2** and **poi-ooxml-5.2.2** and **commons-collections4-4.4** JAR files. I tried adding them to external Libraries by opening Files-Project Structure - Libraries - +. They were added to the External Libraries List but do not work. I also added dependencies to the POM file:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

It did not help either. Please, I have a project deadline soon and I can not finish it without it creating an Excel file.

Comment: Are you using Modules or Classpath?

Comment: Why do you write “unnamed module” in your question title when the posted error message clearly contains a named module (`org.apache.poi.ooxml`)?